# Regular Expression for a Persons Initials

Tags: regex, posix

I have a requirement to validate a persons Initials against the following rules:

1. Must Start with an Alpha (A-Z)
2. Must End with an Alpha (A-Z)
3. Alpha Characters Must be separated by either a Space or Hyphen

This is as far as I have got:

```
^[[:alpha:]]([[:alpha:]]|([[:blank:]-])[[:alpha:]])*([[:blank:]-][:alpha:]|[:alpha:])?$
```

It does 1 and 2 (and allows for spaces and hyphens) but does not ensure that alpha characters are separated by either a space or hyphen i.e AD evaluates to true.

Thanks for any help. I am pretty new to Regular Expressions so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([A-Z][ -])*[A-Z]$
-                     start
 -         --         any number of times
  -----                 a capital letter
       ----             followed by exactly one separator (space or hyphen)
             -----    followed by a final (and possibly initial) capital letter
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help. It's useful seeing it written out in English. Appreciate you taking the time to look and help.

Answer (score 0):

Alpha symbols or A-Z?

[:alpha:] == [A-Za-z]

Try this RE:

```
^[A-Z]([\s\-][A-Z])*$

"A B C" = true
"ABC" = false
"123" = false
"A B-C" = true
"A BC" = false
```

Does the RE allow single alpha characters or multiple?